# calculating the value of the expression in Python

Tags: python, list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [python convert a string to an operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117112/python-convert-a-string-to-an-operator)

Hello everyboby!

I just started learning Python and have a simple question.

Is it possible to get an answer (calculate) of this expression?

```
['10', '/', '5']
```

My problem: I convert `'10'` and `'5'` just to `10` and `5`. How can I convert `'/'` just to `/`? I am using Python 2.7

Comment: This is a classical homework exercise. If it is, tag it, if it's not, well, it's a noteworthy first exercise :-)

Answer (score 5):

I think that the best way is :

retrieve the first element of your list and cast it to int

retrieve the third element of your list and cast it to int

map the second element to a function to compute the result

```
import sys

element = ['10', '/', '5']

operators = {
    '/': lambda a, b: a / b,
    '+': lambda a, b: a + b,
    '-': lambda a, b: a - b,
    '*': lambda a, b: a * b,
}

try:
    a = int(element[0])
    b = int(element[2])
    result = operators[element[1]](a, b)

    print result
except:
    sys.exit(1)
```

As ThiefMaster said, you can also use the operator module. Replace this :

```
operators = {
    '/': lambda a, b: a / b,
    '+': lambda a, b: a + b,
    '-': lambda a, b: a - b,
    '*': lambda a, b: a * b,
}
```

by

```
import operator
operators = {
    '/': operator.div,
    '+': operator.add,
    '-': operator.sub,
    '*': operator.mul,
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
eval(''.join(['10', '/', '5']))
```

The above solution would work for any expression. Ex:

```
eval(''.join(['10', '/', '5', '+', '3', '*', '2']))
```

The only problem is that **eval** is evil... If you want to make an expression evaluator you should write a lexer, a syntactic parser, generate the expression's AST and then evaluate it.

Comment: -10 for using eval.. oh wait, i can only do -1!

Comment: @ThiefMaster why is it bad to use eval to evaluate expressions? Isn't that exactly what it's for?

Comment: @Paul Hankin. Depends, if the expression you're evaluating comes from user input, that it represents a huge security hole.

Comment: the OP is learning python so I guess eval'ing takes the fun out of it...

Comment: @Ioan Alexandru Cucu: That depends on wheather its a desktop application or a web application (that the security matter).

Extra: we can validate list items before joining and evaluating. Thats much easier than writing a good parser.

Answer (score 2):

The [`operator` module](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html) contains functions representing operators:

```
import operator
# Now operator.div(a, b) is the same as a / b
```

Answer (score 1):

One way i can think of doing this is to define function and store than into a dictionary that you can pass the operator to.

**code:**

```
def div(x,y):
    return x / y

op_dict = { '/': div }

a = [['10', '/', '5'], ['15','/','3']]

answers = [ op_dict[x[1]](int(x[0]),int(x[2])) for x in a ]

for answer in answers:
    print answer
```

**results in:**

```
2
5
```

**expanded:**

```
import operator

op_dict = { '+': operator.add,
            '-': operator.sub,
            '/': operator.div,
            '*': operator.mul}


a = [['10', '/', '5'], ['15','*','3'], ['11','+','3']]


answers = [ (x, op_dict[x[1]](int(x[0]),int(x[2]))) for x in a ]

for answer in answers:
    print answer
```

**results in:**

```
(['10', '/', '5'], 2)
(['15', '*', '3'], 45)
(['11', '+', '3'], 14)
```

Answer (score 1):

To add something to the existing answers, we can build a recursive evaluator with just a little more code:

```
import operator as op

operations = {"+": op.add, "-": op.sub, "*": op.mul, "/": op.div}

def evaluate(expression):
  if isinstance(expression, list):
    operand1, string_operation, operand2 = expression
    return operations[string_operation](evaluate(operand1), evaluate(operand2))
  else:
    return int(expression)

print(evaluate(["10", "/", "5"])) # 2    
print(evaluate(["10", "/", ["3", "+", "2"]])) # 2
```